How can I change the Caja theme to Dark Mode in Ubuntu Mate?
I was able to set Pluma to dark mode by setting it in preferences.
In Caja the preferences dialogue has lots of tabs but no way to set the theme.
How can I change it so I don't have to have really bright time going through folders?

Dear downvoters: please comment and suggest improvements. Your input is in no way constructive otherwise


Press the windows key or click the Mate Menu on your task bar and select "Control Center"
Start typing "Appearance" int the "Filter" search box in the top left corner or find it under "Look and Feel"
Click on different tiles in the "Theme" tab and you should see any open Caja windows change to reflect your choice straight after the system UI windows do

